# How to verify if json key contains specific value in Wiremock

Tags: json, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have below request URL:

http://localhost:9082/v1/action/query

And I have below requests in wiremock request file:

1. {"queryString":"Select firstname, lastname, workphone, id, accountId from mydetails}

   {
   "request": {
   "method": "POST",
   "url": "/v1/action/query",
   "bodyPatterns" : [ {
   "contains": "queryString=from mydetails"
   } ]
   },
   "response": {
   "status": 200,
   "bodyFileName": "mydetails.json",
   "headers": {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
   }
   }
2. {"queryString":"Select firstname, lastname, workphone, id, accountId from myinfo}

   {
   "request": {
   "method": "POST",
   "url": "/v1/action/query",
   "bodyPatterns" : [ {
   "contains": "queryString=from myinfo"
   } ]
   },
   "response": {
   "status": 200,
   "bodyFileName": "myinfo.json",
   "headers": {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
   }
   }

Now I have same URL for both request. I have to verify if in request body if we are getting table "from myinfo" inside queryString Json key . then myinfo file returned. and if we have "from Mydetails" then my details one called.

Do we have any suggestion for same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matchingJsonPath` functionality to match one or the other.

Assuming a JSON Mapping...

```
{
    "request": {
         ...
        "bodyPatterns": [{
            "matchesJsonPath": "$(@.queryString =~ .*/myinfo/.*)"
        }]
    }
}
```

The exact JsonPath query might need to be fixed, that's just a rough estimate of what I think it would be